# How should I rectify the error "reference to 'p' is ambiguous"?

Tags: c++

With the following code, I get the error:

```
reference to 'p' is ambiguous
```

Why is it so? How can I get rid of that? I want to get "79" as output. Could someone please throw some light. Thanks for your time!

```
int p=3;
namespace {int p=7;}
namespace {int q=9;}

main()
{    
    cout << p << q;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything named `i` in this code. Anyway, have you considered just... not having two variables with the same name?

Comment: Which `p` are you trying to print?

Comment: I am sorry for that, please refresh your page. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Remove either this

```
int p=3;
```

or this

```
namespace {int p=7;}
```

Alternatively, you can place the first declaration inside a namespace:

```
namespace foo
{
  int p=3;
}
```

*or* give the anonymous namespace a name:

```
namespace bar {int p=7;}
```

and then

```
main(){
    std::cout <<bar::p << q;
}
```

Comment: @sree: There is another way I think

Comment: or give the namespace a name.

Comment: @sree well, yes, see edit. Although I don't really see the point of what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

@juanchopanza suggests a good solution. Here is another one: use a qualified name to refer to the variable declared in the global namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

int p=3;
namespace {int p=7;}
namespace {int q=9;}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ::p << q;
    //           ^^^
}
```

Comment: so its not possible to get an o/p 79? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @sree You cannot refer to a member of an anonymous namespace using a fully qualified identifier. So no. You can't get a "79" output.

Comment: @sree: Nikos C. gave you the answer. You need to give a name to the namespace if you want to refer variables in it with a qualified name.

Comment: thank you all. input taken. again thanks for your valuable time !